Что делать, если в OBS скачет битрейт и сильные пропуски кадров именно по сети?
Раньше(под конец февраля) я стримил и все было отлично, не было ни единого пропуска кадров по сети и я мог позволить спокойно выставить битрейт вплоть до 20 тысяч.
Сейчас же неделю бьюсь с этим и не могу никак решить и понять в чем причина.

Что я делал:
Я пробовал разные настройки битрейта.
Полностью почистил пк от лишнего мусора.
Выставлял разный дюплекс.
Вызывал бригаду специалистов от провайдера, да и в общем писал о проблеме провайдеру, но он утверждает, что у них все хорошо.
Обновлял драйвера видеокарты, без толку.
Стримлю на видеокарте(H.264, RTX3070)
p.s на картинке вот такие вот цифры пропусков кадров.
